# How can I get Unit Tests to run against the appropriate DLL when the DLL cannot be referenced in the project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, resharper, build-process

I've got the following "Pre Build Event" working for my powershell builds (including our Continuous Integration). It simply moves a DLL into the output directory based on the Processor Architecture.

```
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'=='AMD64' (copy /y "$(ProjectDir)x64\sqlite3.dll" "$(OutDir)") 
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'=='x86' (copy /y "$(ProjectDir)x86\sqlite3.dll" "$(OutDir)")
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432)'=='AMD64' (copy /y "$(ProjectDir)x64\sqlite3.dll" "$(OutDir)")
```

The problem I'm running into is when I run the Resharper Unit Tests within the IDE. When I do this, the Pre Build event doesn't run, and therefore all of the tests that depend on the `sqlite3.dll` fail.

What I need to do is either be able to move the appropriate file into the output directory before the Test Runner runs, OR make sure the Test Runner runs against ONLY the x86 Architecture, whereby I can just drop the appropriate file in the `bin\debug` folder and be done with it.

## Things I've tried:

1. I've tried setting the "Build Settings" to "Always Build" but this has no affect on the outcome. It appears as though the build in the IDE doesn't run the Pre Build Event
2. I've also tried to set the default platform architecture in [Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit Testing] - [as per the docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing.html), but unfortunately my version of R# doesn't have that option (7.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the C# project to be 32 bit only, and the ReSharper runner will only run it as 32 bit. That way, you can drop the x86 dll in the bin\debug folder and it should all just work.